# Show Filters on Global search results

Tags: global-search

When we do a global search and if there are no results returned, then we cannot see the "Show filters" option on the selected object which we run the search on. However we can see the "Show filters" link for all the objects where there were some results returned.

Is there a way to make the "Show filters" display even when there are no results returned; especially when you chose a specific object to be searched from the global search left hand side panel.

Comment: Question - Why would you want to filter a set of zero results ?

Comment: Users are searching for picklist fields in Global search, which does not give them results, so they wanted to see the "Show filters" link and then they can add the search criteria for the fields configured as part of the "Search" layouts.

Comment: Ok. I have hit limitations of the global search UI recently as well, and in my humble opinion what you are after is unfortunately not possible. Neither is a custom button to redirect user elsewhere if no result, as sobject result section wont render at all if no  result. Custom search seems the next likely route to explore...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That's what i thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

The "Show filers" shows up when you add certain search fields on the "Search Filter Fields". This is accessed under the object setting page under the Search Layout's related list.